# Most suitable language for cheque/check printing on Windows Platform

Tags: windows, programming-languages, printing, mfc, gdi

I need to create a simple module/executable that can print checks (fill out the details). The details need to be retried from an existing Oracle 9i DB on the Windows(xp or later)

Obviously, I shall need to define the pixel format as to where the details (Name, amount, etc) are to be filled.

The major constraint is that the client needs / strongly prefers a executable , not code that is either interpreted or uses a VM. This is so that installation is extremely simple. This requirement really cannot be changed.

Now, the question is, how do I do it.
(.NET, java and python are out of the question, unless there is a way around the VMs)

I have never worked with MFC or other native windows APIs. I am also unfamiliar with GDI.

Do I have any other option? Any language that can abstract the complexities and can be packed into a x86 binary?

Also, if not then any code help with GDI would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious possibilities would probably be C, C++, and Delphi. There are a few others such as Ada (e.g., Gnat), but offhand I don't see a lot of reason to favor them (especially for a job this small).

At least the way I'd write this, the language would be *almost* irrelevant. I'd have it run almost entirely by an external configuration file that gave the name of each field, and the location where it should be printed. I'd probably use something like MM_LOMETRIC mapping mode, so Windows will handle most of the translation to real-world coordinates (and use tenths of a millimeter in the configuration file, so you can use the coordinates without any translation).

Probably the more difficult part of this would/will be the database connectivity. There are various libraries around to help out with that, so this won't be terribly difficult, but it's still not (quite) as trivial as the drawing part.

Comment: And I thought the DB connect was the easy part! Thank you, I shall do it with GDI+ / C++.

Comment: @Jinal: I'm not sure why you'd use GDI+ either. It's quite handy for some tasks, but in this case I think it would mostly add extra work. Plain old GDI should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right. To be honest, this project is the first time I am using anything but .NET . Concepts about COM, MFC ,GDI are all alien to me.

Could some one tell me exactly how MFC and GDI are related? Is MFC just a OO wrapper for Windows  API? 

What about the graphics functionality in MFC? Does it wrap the GDI components?

Can I just use MFC for getting the job done?
(Do you think I should post this as a separate question?)

Comment: Yes, MFC is pretty much a wrapper around the Win32 API (including GDI for the graphics). Yes, you could use MFC, though quite a few people would question the wisdom of using MFC for any new code.